# animate or just update constraints works on only half of the views I changed

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a container view with 4 buttons ( [see drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNvp0.png) )

I want to animate the button 3 and 4 ( both have 90 hight ) 
And make the container view change accordingly

So I make both buttons height to be 0, by changing its frame.
And change container hight constraint constant change from 200 to 100
and then call layoutIfNeeded.

I made a button for testing that dose that code.

the problem is that only one of the changes happen !

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGRect frame = button3.frame;
    frame.size.height = 0;
    button3.frame = frame;
    CGRect frame1 = button4.frame;
    frame1.size.height = 0;
   button4.frame = frame1;
    buttonContainerHeightConstraint.constant = 100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

when I click the test button only the container changes it size ! button 3 and 4 are still in the same place but because the container is 100 in height now they are "outside" of it.
only if I click the testButton again only then button 3 and 4 disappears as well

I suppurated it so it will look the way I probably would use it.

```
    - (void)showButton3:(Boolean)show {
    CGRect frame = button3.frame;
    frame.size.height = show ? 90 : 0;
    button3.frame = frame;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
- (void)showButton4:(Boolean)show {
    CGRect frame1 = button4.frame;
    frame1.size.height = show ? 90 : 0;
    button4.frame = frame1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
- (void)shrinkBtnContainer:(Boolean)shrink {
    buttonContainerHeightConstraint.constant = shrink ? 100 : 200;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)testButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self showButton3:false];
    [self showButton4:false];
    [self shrinkBtnContainer:true];    
}
```

and same thing happens after I click the button it first hides the container, and If I click again it hides the buttons.
So what I am doing wrong here ?

---

Side notes:
*I work on ios7 so no stackViews and no anchors :(
*I tried to do it without the animation block and I get the same effect.

---

EDIT*
in the end I deleted buttonContainer hight constraint, made both bottom buttons to have constraint to the buttonContainer and when the 2 button height become 0 ( via height constraint, not frame change ) the container automatically shrinks with them to maintain bottom constraint.

I still want to know why it didn't work at the first place tho

Comment: Mixing auto-layout constraints with explicit frame changes tends to be problematic. Can you add height constraints for your buttons and change the `.constant` as you're doing with your container height constraint?

Comment: why ? maybe its because  the button container is the superView ?